# `npm install` fails on node-gyp rebuild with `env: python: No such file or directory` on mac pro m1

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-gyp

I am trying to do npm install and I am getting the error in my application

System details:
macOS Monterey : version 12.5

chip Apple M1 pro

node version: 14.19.3

node-gyp version: 9.1.0

python version:3.8.9

```
> snappy@6.3.5 install /Users/sanhp/client-access-portal/node_modules/snappy
> prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=14.19.3 runtime=node arch=arm64 libc= platform=darwin)
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/snappy/deps/snappy/snappy-1.1.7/snappy-sinksource.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/snappy/deps/snappy/snappy-1.1.7/snappy-stubs-internal.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/snappy/deps/snappy/snappy-1.1.7/snappy.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/snappy.a
env: python: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/snappy.a] Error 127
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/sanhp/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:285:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/sanhp/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.3/bin/node" "/Users/sanhp/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/sanhp/client-access-portal/node_modules/snappy
gyp ERR! node -v v14.19.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm install is complaining that it cannot find python in the environment. To confirm that is the case run the following command

```
python --version
```

You should get a command not found exception. To resolve install python after which running the above command will tell you the version of python installed. Some versions of python have a slightly different binary name for  example python3 so I recommend you install [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) which can be used to manage multiple versions of python. Follow the instructions in the [README](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/README.md) to install pyenv and python. Once the previous command returns the python version you can then try 'npm install' again.

Comment: thanks for the help, solution did help me to fix my issue

Comment: My Macbook is on M1 Pro chip.  Python 3.10.6 is properly installed  following command `python --version` . I also re-installed `xcode-select --install` . Still have the build problem with snappy-1.1.7

Comment: xcode is not the issue here, see my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 15):

The issue is the missing default python in macos 12. Npm actually tells you

> env: python: No such file or directory

To fix this you need to create a python symlink like so:

For homebrew installed python3:

```
ln -s "$(brew --prefix)/bin/python"{3,}
```

For any python3:

```
ln -s "$(which python3)"{3,}
```

For more information see: https://namespaceit.com/blog/env-python-no-such-file-or-directory-when-building-app-with-xcode

Comment: Great! It worked on my mac. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Python virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment) by executing:

```
    python3 -m venv env 
    source env/bin/activate
```

Now you should be able to run `python --version` and re-run your `npm install`.

Comment: This is not suitable for a working copy of a repo, as it adds (and depends on) the newly created env dir.

Comment: You can ignore the env directory by using .gitignore: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/ignoring-files